# Method to return a list of unknown type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query which returns a list of unknown type values. I want to include this query in a method and get the results using that method

```
public __________ getResult() {
var result = from ps in _context.PurchasingShipments
                     group ps by ps.date.Value.Year into grp
                     select new
                     {
                         Year = grp.Key,
                         Cost = grp.Sum(x => x.NoOfPieces * x.PricePerPiece + x.Micelleneous + x.TransportCost + x.SupplierCommission)
                     };

        return result;
```

}

Above is an example and what should be the return type of the getResult method? Please help

Comment: You are creating an anonymous type in the `select` statement, thus the `result` will be an enumerable of the anonymous type. The only way to return that is as an `IEnumerable<object>`, but if you do, how are you going to use that outside of your `getResult` method? You would be better off creating a specific result type (class) containing the two fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:** I **strongly** recommend you to create a model that contains your properties and return a list of that model.

```
public class CostYearModel {
     public int Year { get; set; }
     public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

An the method will be like below

```
public List<CostYearModel> getResult() {
    var result = from ps in _context.PurchasingShipments
                 group ps by ps.date.Value.Year into grp
                 select new CostYearModel
                 {
                     Year = grp.Key,
                     Cost = grp.Sum(x => x.NoOfPieces * x.PricePerPiece + x.Micelleneous + x.TransportCost + x.SupplierCommission)
                 };

      return result.ToList();
}
```

---

**Solution 2:** If you can't and/or don't want to create a model for this, a **bad** solution will be to return a list of objects. And you can access values with **reflection**.

```
public List<Object> getResult() {
    var result = from ps in _context.PurchasingShipments
                 group ps by ps.date.Value.Year into grp
                 select (new
                 {
                    Year = grp.Key,
                    Cost = grp.Sum(x => x.NoOfPieces * x.PricePerPiece + x.Micelleneous + x.TransportCost + x.SupplierCommission)
                 } as Object);

    return result.ToList();
}
```

The code for accesing values for each property (Cost and Year in your case) will look like below.

```
foreach (var costYear in result)
{
    var properties = costYear.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(costYear, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only return object, You should create a class:

```
public class CostYearModel{
    public int Year {get; set;}
    public int Cost {get; set;}
}
public List<CostYearModel> getResult() {
    var result = from ps in _context.PurchasingShipments
                         group ps by ps.date.Value.Year into grp
                         select new CostYearModel
                         {
                             Year = grp.Key,
                             Cost = grp.Sum(x => x.NoOfPieces * x.PricePerPiece + x.Micelleneous + x.TransportCost + x.SupplierCommission)
                         };

      return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: you may want to change `CustomClass` to `CostYearModel`